# CORS questions with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ionic-framework, cors

I am testing a backend `SOAP API` with Ionic and I am getting `CORS` problems.

The app is launched with `ionic serve` that has `http://localhost:8100` origin

I enabled the `MOESIF CORS and ORIGIN` extension with this configuration:

[image]

When I do a `GET` request to

`http://host/WebService1.asmx?WSDL`

It works fine but when I do a `POST` request to

`http://host/WebService1.asmx`

With a xml body it returns this error.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://host/WebService1.asmx' from origin
>   'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

I have tried whith Safari with the security disabled and works all fine but I need to work with Chrome

What would be doing wrong?

Comment: Your should install CORS plugin on your server.

Comment: In my opinion this is not the problem because with safari works fine